# Maven surefire testng provider runs JUnit tests, but doesn't report results

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, testng

In my project, we have both TestNG and JUnit (actually Spock) tests. So we need to run both, and get results from both. With surefire providers it seemd quite easy, so we did this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

However, after some time I found out that junit tests are run twice. This is not good, because we have a lot of tests, and I'd like to limit the time they are running.

After a little research I found out that `surefire-testng` provider runs both TestNG and JUnit tests. So again it seemed simple - I removed `surefire-junit47` provider.

Well, this was not a good solution either, because it turned out testng provider runs junit tests, but doesn't provide results in `target/surefire-reports/TEST*.xml`. I found only TestNG results there.

Is there any solution to have tests run only once, and results reported?

Comment: could you use surefire for running junit and failsafe for running testng?

Answer (score 0):

I use surefire-testng to run junit tests, but don't have any testng tests in the same run.

I extract the reports using:

```
**/surefire-reports/*.xml
```

You can configure surefire-testng to include or exclude any tests, perhaps you can exclude the junit tests by pattern, then have the junit47 provider run those?

surefire-reports can also be configured to collect junit and/or testng reports.

Later junit tests use annotations rather than naming conventions.  testng seems to recognise this, but default behaviour of surefire-reports seems to be only collect data by naming convention.

I still use naming conventions as well as annotations in my junit tests (Test*/*Test for unit and IT*/*IT for integration), which allows me to control surefire and failsafe better.

Either utilise naming conventions to include tests in surefire plugins default behaviour, or configure the plugins to run specific tests and collect the data you want.