# Use parent pom directory in maven submodules, subsubmodules etc

Tags: maven

I have maven project with following structure:

```
/parent
|- module1
|  |- submoduleA
|  |- submoduleB
|- module2
|- testng.xml
```

In parent, every module and every submodule, there is of course pom.xml. I want `parent/testng.xml` to be used in parent, every module and submodule, in surefire plugin configuration.

So I have surefire configured in parent pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>${basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
            ...
        </plugin>
```

Such configuration does not work, because `${basedir}` is always directory of current module or submodule. So for module1 it is looks for `parent/module1/testng.xml`, for submoduleA it looks for `parent/module1/submoduleA/testng.xml` etc.

I want to use `parent/testng.xml` for every module and submodule. How should I configure surefire to do it?

Comment: A better solution for your problem might be the [maven-remote-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/) or thinking why you have a testng.xml suitefile at all?

Comment: I need testng.xml to overcome this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959039/maven-surefire-testng-provider-runs-junit-tests-but-doesnt-report-results

Answer (score 0):

That's what you need: `${session.executionRootDirectory}`

<sup>If I am not in error, Maven 3 only.</sup>